# How to scrape this line with selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hey so im using selenium and im trying to **scrape** this line:

```
<em id="home-payOrderCommission" data-spm-anchor-id="portals._cps_home.overview.i0.6da22fe0oBPXYk">US $7.68</em>
```

Im trying to **scrape** the $7.68 part but I cant figure out how to do it, I tried by element ID but it doesn't seem to work

This is what I tried:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id("portals._cps_home.overview.i0.2e1b2fe03tjTTD").text
print(search)
```

Comment: 'to scrap this line' means 'to throw this line away like garbage'. The correct term is __scrape__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong **id**

use this instead :

```
id = 'home-payOrderCommission'
```

**in code :**

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id("home-payOrderCommission").text
print(search)
```

or a way better approach here is to use **Explicit waits** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "home-payOrderCommission"))).text)
```

**PS :-**

> .text is a method available in Selenium-Python bindings, basically to
> get the text between the ID tag in your case, and in general to
> extract the text of an web element.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! Would you mind explaining why do I need the .text part? Im a newbie

Comment: `.text` is a method available in Selenium-Python bindings, basically to get the text between the ID tag in your case, and in general to extract the text of an web element. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you, about the Explicit waits, Is it required if the website loads immediately? 
also, wont a time.sleep(3) would do the same?

Comment: see, `time.sleep(3)` is also an explicit wait but worst of it's kind. because with that it will always wait for exact time. with having WebDriverWait(), it would try to find web element after an interval of 500 ms. if found return it, if not raise timeout exception

Comment: You can read more about it here (official website ) https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong locator.
As can be seen from the element you presented, it has `id` attribute with value of `home-payOrderCommission` and `data-spm-anchor-id` attribute with value of `portals._cps_home.overview.i0.6da22fe0oBPXYk`.
So, to use `find_element_by_id` method the value is `home-payOrderCommission`.
Try this:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id("home-payOrderCommission").text
print(search)
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH!
Would you mind explaining why do I need the .text part?
Im a newbie

Comment: Sure. `driver.find_element_by_id("home-payOrderCommission")` returns a web element. You can click it etc. To extract it's text you apply `.text` on the web element object and it gives you the element text